# 曜日を出力するプログラム

Tags: c, アルゴリズム

ある日の曜日を知るプログラムの書き方を教えてほしいです。
実行例はこのようになればいいです。

```
$ ./a.out
年: 1999
月: 10
日: 7
1999年10月7日は木曜日です。
```

Comment: 西暦何年以降かを限定しないと回答するのが難しくなります。たしか1600年以降であれば閏年の考え方が現代の暦と同じになり計算は比較的容易ですが、それ以前を対象とする場合は暦の歴史を理解するがあると思います。

Comment: 簡単にはこの記事が参考になるでしょう。[曜日を求める](https://scrapbox.io/imasaraC/%E6%9B%9C%E6%97%A5%E3%82%92%E6%B1%82%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B) 暦の知識はこちらで。[グレゴリオ暦](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AA%E6%9A%A6), [ユリウス暦](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A6%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B9%E6%9A%A6), [曜日の計算](http://www2.wbs.ne.jp/~ykkym/MathNote/NoteYoubi.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

[ツェラーの公式](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%84%E3%82%A7%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E5%85%AC%E5%BC%8F)を使えばできます。曜日の表し方が少し特殊なことに注意してください。

Answer (score 0):

1年は365日ですから、年数＊365＋求める年の日数を7で割ったら、そのあまりが曜日となります。
求める年の日数とは1月1日からの日数です。
しかし問題はうるう年があることにより、上記の計算ではずれが生じることです。

ですから、正確には、（年数＊365＋求める年の日数＋うるう年の数）を7で割ったあまりとなります。

うるう年は4年に一回ありますが、その中でも100年に一回はうるう年ではありません。
しかし400年に一回はうるう年です。
これにより何回うるう年があったかを求めます。

求めたい年がうるう年の場合、2月29日より前と、2月29日より後では1日のずれが発生しますので
注意が必要です。

うるう年
https://boxil.jp/beyond/a5435/

Answer (score -1):

はやいはなしが西暦１年１月１日からの通算日数を出して、７のあまりを出せばいいということです。
通算日数の出し方はネットを探せばでてきます